# sup norm of operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, compact-operators

Let $T$ be a compact linear operator defined as
$$
T\circ u
=
\int_a^b k(x,y)\,u(y)\,dy,
$$
where $k(x,y)\in C([a,b]\times[a,b])$ and $k(x,y)\ge0$ for all $x,y$, and $u\in C([a,b])$.

Suppose that the spectral radius of $T$ is less than 1 so that the equation $f=1+T\circ f$ has a unique solution. Can one conclude that $\|(I-T)^{-1}\|_\infty=\|f\|_\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the spectral radius of $T$ is less than $1$, then the unique solution of $(I-T)f = 1$ is
$$
    f = 1 + T1 + T^{2}1+T^{3}1+\cdots .
$$
So suppose that $T1=0$. Then the solution is $f=1$ making it unlikely that $\|(I-T)^{-1}\|_{\infty}=\|1\|_{\infty}=1$.

For example, consider $X=C[-1,1]$ and
$$
               Tf = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}xf(x)\,dx.
$$
Then $T$ maps everything to a constant multiple of $1$ and $T1=0$, which gives $T^{2}=0$ and
$$
             (I-T)^{-1}=I+T+T^{2}+T^{3}+\cdots = I+T.
$$
By design, the function $f=1$ is the unique solution of $(I-T)f=1$ because $Tf=0$.
Let $g=x$. Then $(I-T)^{-1}g=(I+T)g=x+1/3$. So
$$
\begin{align}
  \|(I-T)^{-1}\|_{\infty} & \ge \frac{\|(I-T)^{-1}g\|_{\infty}}{\|g\|_{\infty}} \\
        & = \frac{\|x+1/3\|_{\infty}}{\|x\|_{\infty}} \\
        & =\frac{4/3}{1}=4/3 > \|f\|_{\infty}=1.
\end{align}
$$

**Added:** I missed the point that your $k \ge 0$. That does give you what you want because $f \le g$ on $[a,b]$ implies $Tf \le Tg$. In particular,
$$
                          |Tf| \le T|f| \le T(\|f\|1)=\|f\|T1.
$$
This also holds for all powers of $T$ because $T^{2}$ will have a positive kernel, etc. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
  |(I-T)^{-1}f| & \le |(I+T+T^{2}+T^{3}+\cdots)f| \\
               & \le (I+T+T^{2}+\cdots)|f| \\
               & \le \|f\|(I+T+T^{2}+\cdots)1 \\
               & \le \|f\|(I-T)^{-1}1.
\end{align}
$$
So you definitely have $\|(I-T)^{-1}f\|\le \|(I-T)^{-1}1\|\|f\|$ which implies
$$
                           \|(I-T)^{-1}\| \le \|(I-T)^{-1}1\|.
$$
On the other hand, the opposite inequality holds because
$$
                            \|(I-T)^{-1}1\| \le \|(I-T)^{-1}\|\|1\|=\|(I-T)^{-1}\|
$$

Comment: Well, when $k(x,y)=y$ and $b=-a=1$, as in your example, then the condition $k(x,y)\ge0$ is violated. Would the claim that $\|(I-T)^{-1}\|_\infty=\|f\|_\infty$ be true if $T$ had only the zero function in its null space?

Comment: @Jason : I missed that condition on $k$. I'll have to think more about this.

Comment: Heuristically, if $T$ were a matrix, then the claim would be true. So I am guessing when $T$ is an integral operator the claim is also true but under certain conditions.

Comment: @Jason : If $k \ge 0$, then $Tf \le Tg$ if $f \le g$, and that may be enough to get what you want because $|Tf| \le T|f| \le \|f\|T1$. I think the same would hold for $T^{n}$ and, therefore, for $(I-T)^{-1}=I+T+T^{2}+T^{3}+\cdots$. Check that and see if it works.

Comment: @Jason : I had more time, so I fleshed out the last remark in the post.

Comment: Great, thanks much.